# Relationship between the core of the quotient game of a convex game G and the projection of the core of G onto the a priori coalitions?

Tags: game-theory

I am applying cooperative game theory to the question of how the structure of a value chain affects the distribution of profits among the contributing firms.

I am struggling with the following. Let $G$ be a convex game with characteristic function $v$ and player set $N$, where $|N|=n$. Let $B$ be a partition of $N$ into $m$ a priori unions, $b_1, ..., b_m$. The partition $B$ induces a quotient game $G'$ between the a priori unions, which has the core $C'$. Now consider a mapping from $R^n$ to $R^m$, $x \mapsto f(x) = y$, such that the allocation $y_k$ of a priori union $b_k$ equals the sum of the allocations $x_i$ of all members of this a priori union.

My question is: is the core of $G'$ identical to the mapping of the core of $G$ under $f(\cdot)$, i.e., $C' = f(C)$? I have a hunch that this is the case, but could neither devise a proof nor find a counter-example.

I'd be grateful for any hints or references.

Thanks,
Joachim

Comment: Can you define the game $G'$?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: this is a correction of a previous answer.

The answer is "yes."

The direction $C'\supset f(C)$ is simple, so I will show that $C'\subset f(C)$. Since $f(C)$ is a convex set it is sufficient to show that the extreme points of $C'$ are in $f(C)$. The game $G'$ is convex; therefore any extreme point $y\in C'$ is obtained by ordering the players in some linear order, say wlog in the order $b_1,\ldots,b_m$, and setting $y_k= v(\cup_{l\leq k}b_l)-v(\cup_{l< k}b_l)$ (See: Shapley (1971) https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01753431).

Extend the ordering $b_1,\ldots,b_m$ to an order of $N=\{1,\ldots n\}$. Say wlog, $b_k=\{i:|\cup_{l< k}b_l|<i\leq |\cup_{l\leq k}b_l|\}$. Now, take $x\in C$, defined by $x_i=v(1,\ldots,i)-v(1\ldots,i-1)$. Since $x(b_k)$ is a telescopic sum that equals $y_k$, we have $f(x)=y$ as desired.

Comment: Very nice - thank you so much! Could you let me know your name so that I can ackowledge your help in the paper? My email is henkel@wi.tum.de.

Comment: Sorry, my earlier comment was premature. After a more careful look at your proposed proof, I think the last step has a bug: With superadditivity, the inequality is reversed. Also, x will in general not be in C:  The way x is constructed implies that x(S)≥v(S) if S is either a subset of one a priori union b_k or a union of a number of complete a priori unions. However, if S contains subsets of two or more a priori unions and at least one of them is a proper subset then the construction does not ensure that x(S)≥v(S). Hence, x may violate one or more of the conditions defining C.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. My oroof was wrong, but I thing the statement is still true. I thing it can be proved by noting that the core of a convex game can be realized by taking the marginal contribution of the players along an ordering of them. Such an ordering of the players of G' can be extended to an ordering of the players of G. I'll try to write it down. This time I'll be more careful. My name is Ron Peretz.